# IE8 appendChild to XML issue: Type Mismatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, appendchild

I am working on an xml using jquery and javascript. I import xml using ajax then i want to manipulate it, appendChild is a problem in IE8.

This is the Javascript:

```
// How i get xml 
$.ajax({
  url: production_get,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) {
      input_xml=data;
  }
});

// how i try to append a new node to 

new_user_node = document.createElement('user');
new_user_node.setAttribute('id',new_user_id);
new_user_node.setAttribute('label',new_user_label);        

response=$(input_xml)[0].getElementsByTagName("response")[0];
response.appendChild(new_user_node); // <- type mismatch
```

XML markup

```
<response>
    <user id="123" label="John" />
</response>
```

This works great in all browser but IE that reports: Type Mismatch. I have to say it works even in IE8 but console reports the error, while in IE7 the error popup appears

Comment: At which line this error comes ?

Comment: i improved the original question with details

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap xml in jQuery it treats the xml as html. This allows traversing to get attributes and text, but is not sufficent for modifying the xml.

To create an XML doc to append to you need to use `$.parseXML()`

```
/* First create xml doc*/
var xmlDoc=$.parseXML(input_xml);

/*Create jQuery object of xml doc*/
var $xml= $( xmlDoc);

/*Now append*/
$xml.append( new_user_node);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

More examples in API

Comment: when i try to import the xml: success: function(data){input_xml=data;} using $.parseXML(data) i receive Invalid XML: [object XMLDocument] but xml looks valid to me